# Why is this logic incorrect?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $S = 1 + x + x^{2} + \dots$

Then $xS = x + x^{2} + \dots$

Thus $S - xS = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x}$

Clearly this isn't correct. Otherwise we would have $x=-1$ giving two different sums for the series.

Where is the error in the logic? I'm thinking perhaps on the division to arrive at $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but I can't quite see why.

Comment: What is it about $x=-1$ you find instructive?

Comment: It works if "$S = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$" makes sense.

Comment: @J.G. well if $x=-1$ then we can say $1-1+1-1+\dots = \frac{1}{2}$ But I could group the terms as $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots = 0$ Or even $1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\dots = 1$.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is the **radius of convergence**. $S = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for any $x<1$.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner You've rediscovered [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten upto radius of convergence yet but I'll take a look :). The answers make sense though.

Comment: erratum : $S=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for any $x$ (even complex!) with $|x| < 1$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*If* a finite value $S:=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ exists, this argument shows $S=\frac{1}{1-x}$. *Whether* it exists is the real problem. It doesn't if $|x|\ge1$, because a convergent infinite series has terms that tend to $0$. On the other hand, it *does* work if $|x|<1$, as can be shown by noting$$\frac{1}{1-x}-(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})=\frac{x^n}{1-x},$$which approaches $0$ as $n$ grows.

Answer (score 3):

Let consider a finite sum

$$S_n = 1 + x + x^{2} + \dots+ x^{n}$$

$$xS_n = x + x^2 + x^{3} + \dots+ x^{n+1}$$

then
$$S_n-xS_n=1-x^{n+1} \implies S_n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

which is always true for $x\neq 1$ moreover for $|x|<1$ in the limit as $n\to \infty$

$$S_\infty = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

since $x^{n+1}\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The infinite series $$S = 1 + x + x^{2} + \dots$$ converges for $$-1<x<1$$ which is its interval of convergence.

That is if you have an $x$ value which is between $-1$ and $1$, then the infinite  series converges to $\frac {1}{1-x}$

On the other hand if you choose an $x$ which is not in the interval of convergence, the series does not converge to a real number so the formal expansion results in seemingly meaningless identities.

Comment: Yes, that was the argument I would use too. OP's logic is not incorrect, it only has a domain of validity. (which is $(-1,1)$). Unfortunately applying for $x=1$ is precisely what we cannot do...

Comment: @zwim  You are correct, the logic seems to be correct formally.